# Wrap with Space between and Start Alignment in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a wrap with start alignment and it shows like this.

[image]

In my case, I do not want the free space that you see on the right to remain. I can fix this with space between alignment and it looks like this.

[image]

But in this case I don't want the last line, having 3 items, to be placed that way, if not in the way that start alignment provides me.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use `Wrap` for that.

Comment: And there some widget that can do what I'm looking for

Comment: This sounds like it'd be solved by a GridView. If the default options for GridView don't fit your needs I think you can even provide a custom delegate to space things exactly how you like

Answer (score 2):

*Flutter 3.10.**

You can try to wrap the `Wrap` in `SizedBox`:

```dart
SizedBox(
    width: double.maxFinite,
    child: Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [...],
    ),
),
```

In this case `double.maxFinite` fill all possible width (don't set height if you use `Column`) and `WrapAlignment.spaceBetween` set space between children

P.S.
I have this structure of my page:

```
Expanded -> SingleChildScrollView -> Column -> Padding -> Column -> Wrap
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this by calculating spacing value:

```
Wrap(
  spacing: _calculateSpacing(),
  alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
  children: tiles,
);

double _calculateSpacing() {
  return _calculateSpacingWith(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    tileWidth: _TileWidget.width,
    minSpacing: 4,
  );
}

double _calculateSpacingWith({
  required double width, 
  required double tileWidth,
  required double minSpacing,
}) {
  // N = tilesInRow
  // tileWidth * N + spacing * (N-1) = width
  final tilesInRow = ((width + minSpacing) / (tileWidth + minSpacing)).floor();
  if (tilesInRow <= 1) {
    return 0;
  }

  final spacing = ((width - tileWidth * tilesInRow) / (tilesInRow - 1)).floorToDouble();
  return spacing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While `WrapAlignment.spaceBetween` creates empty space between items in each row, it's normal to have this result in a row with less items. In this case, you can specify spacing dynamically. Here's how I solved my problem by using `LayoutBuilder`:

```
return LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    double widthOfTheChild = 100;
    final countOfChildsInARow = constraints.maxWidth ~/ widthOfTheChild;
    final emptySpace = constraints.maxWidth - (widthOfTheChild * countOfChildsInARow);
    final spacing = emptySpace / (countOfChildsInARow - 1);
    return Wrap(
      spacing: spacing,
      runSpacing: 24,
      children: List.generate(
      activeRewards.length, 
      (index)
      {
        final reward = activeRewards.elementAt(index);
        return _rewardWidget(context, reward);
      }
      ).toList(),
    );
  }
);
```